# Set the number of bits

Tags: set, bit

How can I set a variable to have a certain number of bits? For example I want to set x to have 3 bits, and if I copy 9=1001 in x, x will hold 100.

Comment: What programming language? And if `x` had 3 bits and you assigned `x = 1001` you'd get `1` normally, not `100`. At least in cases where bit fields are supported.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In C you can do something like this:

```
struct foo {
    int field1:3;
}
```

And field1 of a foo would only occupy 3 bits.